# Publications and International Standard for bibliographic references

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

I'm applying for a job which requires the list of all publications.
Quoting the call:

> Publications over the last 10 years in chronological order within each category following the **International Standard for bibliographic references** with DOI whenever possible.

I'm a bit confused because I have no clue how to write my publications in this format. 
Since I'm a computer scientist I usually take the bibtex from databases like DBLP or Scholar, but I'm not sure if it's equivalent for this International Standard.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched for this citation style? There is even a wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Bibliographic_Description. There is an example which gives you an hint how you should structure your bibliographic reference. If a certain element of the list can't be applied to one of your publications , you could leave it out/not mention it. 
 My guess would be that official university catalogs use this or a similar style and you could consult these to make sure you do it right.